# Neo4j Cypher query error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am facing an issue while I am trying to execute a query in neo4j.

The expected result is to get the products that belong to a certain marketplace and have relation to ProductFeed, starting from marketplace

Query

```
MATCH (marketplace:`Marketplace`), 
(marketplace)-[rel_has_product_products:HAS_PRODUCT]->(products:`Product`),
 (product:`Product`), 
(product)-[rel_has_product_feed_productFeed:HAS_PRODUCT_FEED]->(productFeed:`ProductFeed`) 
WITH product, 
count(productFeed) AS productFeed_count
 WHERE id(marketplace) = 123481 
and productFeed_count >= 1 
RETURN product
```

The error I get is `marketplace not defined (line 1...` at `id(marketplace) =`

I don't see why marketplace is not defined

Comment: I'm rather confused about your query. You match from marketplace to its products...but you never use the `products` in that marketplace. Instead, you have an alternate match to `product`, which is matching to every product with a ProductFeed. Basically your marketplace match isn't doing anything in your query at all. Didn't you want to work with products within a particular marketplace? Because your query isn't doing that.

Comment: Thats a good point. I am making a query builder that resulted in the above query, and I do have only one marketplace in my project right now, so I overlooked at that issue. Thank you for pointing out, i will try to fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

marketplace is not defined as variable, you should pass it in the WITH clause

```
MATCH (marketplace:`Marketplace`), 
(marketplace)-[rel_has_product_products:HAS_PRODUCT]->(products:`Product`),
 (product:`Product`), 
(product)-[rel_has_product_feed_productFeed:HAS_PRODUCT_FEED]->(productFeed:`ProductFeed`) 
WITH product, marketplace, 
count(productFeed) AS productFeed_count
 WHERE id(marketplace) = 123481 
and productFeed_count >= 1 
RETURN product
```

Comment: Exactly, thank you, i really missed that! I am going to mark the answer as soon as it is available

Answer (score 1):

You have only taken `product` in WITH clause. `marketplace` should also be taken to further process.

Modified query

```
MATCH (marketplace:`Marketplace`), 
(marketplace)-[rel_has_product_products:HAS_PRODUCT]->(products:`Product`),
 (product:`Product`), 
(product)-[rel_has_product_feed_productFeed:HAS_PRODUCT_FEED]->(productFeed:`ProductFeed`) 
WITH product, marketplace,
count(productFeed) AS productFeed_count
 WHERE id(marketplace) = 123481 
and productFeed_count >= 1 
RETURN product
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using a `WITH` clause to connect different *sub queries*. Only variables that are explicitly stated in the `WITH` clause are carried forward to the next clause.

```
MATCH (marketplace:`Marketplace`) ...
WITH product, count(productFeed) AS productFeed_count
WHERE id(marketplace) = 123481 and productFeed_count >= 1 
RETURN product
```

You're not carrying `marketplace` into the `WITH` clause. So the correct way would be to either add the `WHERE` condition to the initial `MATCH` or carry `marketplace` into the `WITH`clause:

```
MATCH (marketplace:`Marketplace`), 
    (marketplace)-[rel_has_product_products:HAS_PRODUCT]->(products:`Product`),
    (product:`Product`), 
    (product)-[rel_has_product_feed_productFeed:HAS_PRODUCT_FEED]->(productFeed:`ProductFeed`) 
WHERE id(marketplace) = 123481 
WITH product, count(productFeed) AS productFeed_count
WHERE productFeed_count >= 1 
RETURN product
```

or

```
MATCH (marketplace:`Marketplace`), 
    (marketplace)-[rel_has_product_products:HAS_PRODUCT]->(products:`Product`),
    (product:`Product`), 
    (product)-[rel_has_product_feed_productFeed:HAS_PRODUCT_FEED]->(productFeed:`ProductFeed`) 
WITH marketplace, product, count(productFeed) AS productFeed_count
WHERE id(marketplace) = 123481 AND productFeed_count >= 1 
RETURN product
```

It seems as if option (1) would be the better way from a performance perspective as it eliminates unneeded paths (those not starting a marketplace `123481`) very early in the process.

Answer (score 1):

While everyone else is correct that the fix for the problem in your question is to include `marketplace` in your WITH clause to keep it in scope, there's a more serious problem with your query that's being overlooked.

You have a match from a marketplace to `products:Products`, but you never actually use the `products` variable again in the entire query. Instead, you have a separate match to a new `product` variable that's matching to all :Products. You aren't constraining the products you're working with to a particular marketplace at all.

So let's fix this. There are also a number of other improvements to make:

1. We should also make sure we constrain `marketplace` to the marketplace you want early, not at the end.
2. We can get rid of any variables you aren't going to use, so let's ditch the relationship variables.
3. You seem to only be matching from a product to its product feed for the sole purpose of making sure it has a product feed. We can do this easier and sooner by making this part of the WHERE clause on the first MATCH, making sure the `product`s we match on have a product feed.

All of this makes for much more concise and efficient query.

```
MATCH (marketplace:`Marketplace`)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(product:`Product`)
WHERE id(marketplace) = 123481 AND (product)-[:HAS_PRODUCT_FEED]->(:`ProductFeed`)
RETURN product
```

Comment: Thats a good point. I am making a query builder that resulted in the above query, and I do have only one marketplace in my project right now, so I overlooked at that issue. Thank you for pointing out, i will try to fix that!